# loop html table using jquery and for loop (not for each)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML table

```
 <table id="mytab">
  <thead>
    <th>col1</th>
    <th>col2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>11</td>
     <td>22</td>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

and i am writing the jquery function

```
  function LoopTable()
  {
      $row = $('#mytab tbody >tr"); //here I have successfully find all the rows.

     //now i want to loop on rows and find each column row
     for (var i=0; i<$rows.length; i++)
     {
         //need something here to find col data

     }
```

what I should use to have column values from row

Comment: dump the $row value , you may get clue

Comment: Meaning: try console.dir($row) in your browsers dev console (press f12 in IE/Chrome to open it)

Comment: And you don't want to use each() method? You need each td value, or?

Comment: because I want to work with only some columns and rows thats why I don't want to use each() method, I want somthing $rows[i].cells[0].val()

Comment: a lot of mistakes are in OP code. such as `'` closing with `"` and $row is initialize and `$rows` is used in for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rows = $('#mytab tbody >tr');
    var columns;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        columns = $(rows[i]).find('td');
        for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
            console.log($(columns[j]).html());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i<$rows.length; i++)
{
    $.each($row[i].children("td"), function(key, value) {
         console.log(value);
    });
}
```